# How to change style of the page based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a page where some style will change when the user click on a button, but, the page should get on load the first button selected.

I make this code to run on load and apply the first class:

```
$(function() {$('button.volt:first').addClass('voltActive');});
```

And this to change the class applied:

```
changeClass: function () {
   $("button.volt").removeClass('voltActive');
   $("button.volt").toggleClass('voltActive');
}
```

That's my css:

```
.volt{
  font-size: 20px;
  border-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: dotted;
  margin-left: 25px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 135px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.voltActive{
 border-color: blue;
 border-style: solid;
 outline: none;
}
```

And that's my button:

```
<button data-bind="click:$parents[1].changeClass()" class="volt"></button>
```

But isn't working. Could someone help me?

Comment: Your `changeClass` function will always end up with the `voltActive` class on.  Your remove it (off) and then you toggle it (always on).

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass()` changes the state of the class. If it's already on the control it will remove it, if it's not on the control it will add it. So you are removing it then calling `toggleClass` to add it again.

Just toggle it.

```
changeClass: function () {
          $("button.volt").toggleClass('voltActive');
}
```

Comment: Now it's working the toggle, but not selecting the first button on load as I want in 
`$(function() {$('button.volt:first').addClass('voltActive');});`

Comment: It's selecting the second element, that's what I mean in ` but not selecting the first button on load `

Comment: @MateusFernando Try: $(function(){$('button.volt').first().addClass('voltActive');});

Comment: @LenapCapo 's comment will sort it - unless your js is running before the controls are rendered in which case move the script to the bottom of the page

Comment: Isn't working here, maybe cause I need to use this on onLoad or beforeAppear.

Comment: I have another question...I know it's a new question not related to the main one, but maybe it's something simple. I'm using KnockoutJs and I need to make the button upload some values and do the function, but now it's only running the second one (the function, not the value update). Someone know how to use both at same time?

Comment: Post it as another question